# Remove php $_SESSION variable after a set period of time

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make the success message generated by this code disappear after x seconds....PS: this code is on a separate file

```
if(isset($_SESSION['success_flash']))
    {
        echo '<div class="bg-success"><p class="text-success text-center">'.$_SESSION['success_flash'].'</p></div>';
        unset($_SESSION['success_flash']);
    }
```

if the condition of an if statement has been met and has this code inserted in it

```
$_SESSION['success_flash'] = '*message';
```

a message would pop up on top of the website, what should I target if I'm gonna use the javascript function `setTimeout` or if there are other ways to do it...TIA

Comment: What have you tried, post it.

Comment: got it thanks......................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to that div and get it on document ready, and remove it after x seconds.

Like this:

```
echo '<div class="bg-success flash-message"><p class="text-success text-center">'.$_SESSION['success_flash'].'</p></div>';


$(function(){
    $(".flash-message").each(function(){
        var $that = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $that.remove();
        }, 5000); //5 seconds
    });
});
```